# How to send a .ZIP file to Web Service

Tags: asp.net, web-services

How to send a .ZIP file to Web Service using ASP.NET(C#)
Is Impossible?

Comment: What do you mean by "web service"? What do you mean by "send a .ZIP file"? Do you want to send the file, or unzip it and send the contents?

Comment: Or are you trying just to let the user upload the ZIP file?

Answer (score 1):

You can convert the file to a byte array and pass that array to the service:

```
var fs = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
var fileData = new byte[fs.Length];
fs.Read(fileData, 0, Convert.ToInt32(fs.Length));
fs.Close();
```

Just pass `fileData` to the web service as a method argument or however you would normally pass a value in your setup.  (Personally I prefer request/response style service layers rather than webmethods, but to each his own.)

Comment: Hımm thanks.
I dont want to file with method argument.
Is only way send with argument?

Comment: @Murat: It depends on your web service setup.  Does your service just expose web methods?  If so then that's what the service _does_ is expect method arguments.

Comment: @David: I ve done this, but is it possible to read this file at the webservice and then save it somewhere physically?

Comment: @AJ: Of course it is.  Once you have the byte array you can do whatever you like with it.  If you also need to carry more information (such as the file name, maybe the content type, other meta-data) then instead of just the byte array you can create a custom DTO class which is just an empty class with default get/set parameters.  One parameter is the byte array, one is a string for the name, etc.  Then the web service can use all of that data to determine what to do with the file.

Answer (score 1):

If the files might be large you probably want to use a chunking method to get them sent so you can provide feedback to your users:

[CodeProject - Sending Files in Chunks with MTOM Web Services and .NET 2.0](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/XML/MTOMWebServices.aspx)